# LyX: How to make lowered letters for nomenclature?

Tags: lyx, nomenclature

I want to have a lowered letters for my nomenclature.

This is my LyX-Passage:

[image]

But it looks like this when I print the Pdf:

[image]

How can do this?

Comment: does someone know?

Comment: When you define the entry you have a Symbol field. put the "lowered letters" there.